# Determinantal formula for the volume of a convex hull

Tags: geometry, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Let $d$ be an integer. I will work in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Let $N$ be an integer and $x_0,x_1,\cdots x_N$ be $N+1$ points of $\mathbb{R^d}$.

If $N=d$, then I have $d+1$ points and $Vol(Conv(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_d))=\frac{det(x_1-x_0,x_2-x_0,\cdots x_d-x_0)}{d!}$ because we can view it as a linear transformation of the simplex which is of measure $1/d!$.

However is there the same kind of formula if $n$ is strictly bigger than $d$? Or at least useful bounds on the volume of $Conv(x_0,x_1,\cdots x_n)$ when $N$ is big?

Of course the formula above can not be true anymore because it will just be zero.

Comment: Useful bounds in terms of what?

Answer (score 0):

The volume of the convex set is no greater than the sum of the volumes of the simplices spanned by $N+1$-tuples of points, so the sum of determinants will be a bound. How useful it is depends on what you want to use it for...

Comment: Yes, It would be indeed a bound but it will be very rough. With this bound the volume will be counted many times. Perhaps is it possible to get something like $Vol\leq C\frac{\sum det(\Delta_i)}{n}$. I tried to prove it by induction on $n$. However you have to consider two cases: when you add a point inside the convex hull and when you add a point outside. This second case seems to be much more complicated.